# Highlight table row using knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to learn Knockout. I want to highlight a table row when clicking on an link within the row. I'm having a hard time understanding the context of `this`, `e` and how knockout interacts with `JQuery`. Can I not build knockout functions just as standard jquery functions?

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Cat</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: components">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a data-bind="text: Name, click: $parent.highlightComponent" href="#"></a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Category"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Size"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then my view model...

```
function MyViewModel() {

    this.components = ko.observableArray();
    this.selectedComponent = ko.observable();

    this.highlightComponent = function(e) {

        console.log($(this).parents("tr"));

        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("diffColor");
        $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("diffColor", e.clicked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `IsHighlighted` property on each item in the `components` array to indicate whether the item is highlighted:

```
this.IsHighlighted = ko.observable(false);
```

Then in your HTML, turn on that property upon `click` and have your `TR.diffColor` class bound to that property:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: components">
        <tr data-bind="css: { diffColor: IsHighlighted }">
            <td></td>
            <td><a data-bind="text: Name, click: IsHighlighted" href="#"></a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Category"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Size"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Update:**

As per your request to only allow one highlighted item at a time, try to add `HighlightedRowIndex` observable to the root view-model:

```
this.HighlightedRowIndex = ko.observable();
```

And in your HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: components">
    <tr data-bind="css: { diffColor: $root.HighlightedRowIndex() == $index }">
        <td></td>
        <td><a data-bind="text: Name, click: $root.HighlightedRowIndex.bind(null, $index)" href="#"></a></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Category"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Size"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I'm getting `IsHighlighted is not defined`. `components` is coming from server side json. Can't I loop through them and add the IsHighlighted member? `ko.utils.arrayForEach(model.components, function(item) { item.IsHighlighted = ko.observable(false); });`

Comment: Do you also need to toggle (on/off state) the highlight or turn it on upon first click?

Comment: Ultimately I want to only have 1 row in the entire table to be highlighted, so clicking another row would need to un-highlight anything previously highlighted.

Comment: @haim770 `$index` is an observable, and observables are functions. Therefore `$root.HighlightedRowIndex() == $index()` (notice the parentheses).