# knockoutjs - highlight table row with hasFocus subscription

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to figure out how to highlight my table row when a given input receives focus in that row.  I have a hasFocus observable that has a subscription function that already does some stuff.  But I think I need the row index and not sure how to get that index into the function.  I did find another SO Q&A which helped me out some, but not all the way.  [Highlight table row using knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391390/highlight-table-row-using-knockout-js)

Here is my table of rows with inputs(all observable):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
                <tr data-bind="css: { diffColor: $root.HighlightedRowIndex() == $index }">
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: itemNo, insertPress: $index, deletePress: $index, hasFocus: invalidItemNum, selected: invalidItemNum, event: { blur: function(){ $parent.checkItemNo($data, $index); } }, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__itemNo', tabindex: 4 + $index()}" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: qty, insertPress: $index, tabEnterPress: '#tallyEntry', hasFocus: qtyFocus, deletePress: $index, event: { blur: function(){ $parent.calcTotal($data); } }, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].qty', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__qty', tabindex: 5 + $index() }" class="form-control" />
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: locCode, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].locationCode', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__locationCode' }" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: price, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].retail', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__retail' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: bro, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].brocCode', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__brocCode' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" />
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: broID, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].brochureId', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__brochureId' }" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: desc, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].itemDesc', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__itemDesc' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: total, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].total', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__total' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: seq, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].itemRow', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__itemRow' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

And here is my KO subscription where I want to highlight the row:

```
self.invalidItemNum.subscribe(function() {
  easyGlanceModel.bigItemNo(self.itemNo());
  easyGlanceModel.bigQty(self.qty());
  self.highlightedRowIndex(???)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give advice without seeing the bigger picture. My recommendation would be to pass an index to the `item` when you create it. Add it as an observable and then you can reference `self.index` which should match it's index within the parent `items`

I'm assuming you're populating `items` with an array of JSON data or something similar, so it should be as simple as adding

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    self.items.push(new itemViewModel({
        itemNo: data[i].itemNo,
        qty: data[i].qty,
        index: i
    }));
}
```

again, I'm making the assumption that you built the constructor to take an object for initial values. Regardless, do you get the idea?

Comment: Seems odd that I can't just pass $index over in the hasFocus function.

Comment: So make `index` another observable in a hidden input?

Comment: you could try changing your focus from `invalidItemNum` to `function(){ $data.setInvalidItemNum($index) }` and then define `setInvalidItemNum` on your item view model

Comment: You shouldn't have to have `index` displayed anywhere (even as a hidden input) just having it as an observable on the viewmodel should be sufficient

Comment: I figured out how to set the highlightedRowIndex to the correct number, but the class is not getting added.  `self.invalidItemNum.subscribe(function() {
            self.highlightedRowIndex(parseInt(self.seq())-1);
            console.log("hri: " + self.highlightedRowIndex());
        });`

Comment: your binding looks correct. Maybe try changing the binding to `text: $root. highlightedRowIndex() + " " + $index` just to physically see the values

Comment: That hint helped me see that $root.highlightedRowIndex() was undefined and I was able to play around with it enough to figure out that I needed to change it to $data.highlightedRowIndex() and that fixed it!  Thank you!

Comment: OK, nevermind, I had something screwed up in my viewmodels.  $root is now working, rock on!